# Database normalisation with custom ORM support

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, orm

We have a database that we are currently slowly working at reconstructing. We have an in-house ORM that we've created that interacts with our database and provides us with functionality within the code. To give a basic structure rundown, here is what we have:

Records table - this stores files, using a REC### number as it's identifier.
Records link table - this links our records with the REC### to a column within the table, where there is data.

`RECORD | PART | ASSET | SERIAL | TASK | SERIAL`

Now, we have null values where the link doesn't exist.

`REC123 | NULL | NULL | NULL | ABC123 | NULL`

This doesn't seem like the way to go, seeing as a record can have multiple links:

`REC123 | PART1 | NULL | NULL | ABC123 | NULL`

So we're stuck with three idea's, possibly more, as to how we can go about solving this predicament.

### **Option 1:**

---

We have one table that handles the links, and links based on the primary key identifier in each of the respective tables, with a `RecordType` column that allows it to distinguish between the different record types. This method doesn't work too well with our in-house ORM, but open to suggestions.

RecordLink - `Record | RecordType | RecordRowID`

and in a seperate RecordType table, we have: `Type | TypeID` which links to the RecordType.

### **Option 2:**

---

We extract each of the columns into a separate table each and add a new table everytime we want to create new links. This would mean PART-RECORDLINK, ASSET-RECORDLINK, etc. etc. with

`ID | RECORD | LINKID` as columns. This helps in the coding aspect, and our in-house ORM.

### **Option 3:**

---

We keep the aforementioned table structure, and simply add columns when we want to create a new link. This however results in a large amount of null columns, and in coding presents itself as an issue as we have to find which of the columns has data present, and instantiate new objects based on the data. This one works well with our in-house ORM.

`RECORD | PART | ASSET | SERIAL | TASK | SERIAL | BATCH | NEWLINK | NEWLINK 2` etc.

---

We also have this issue in other tables that have multiple links - what we've done to overcome that is to add in a prefix to the value, but feel that this is not the way to go - i.e

`... | LOCATION | ...`

`... | <c>123   | ...`

`... | <s>123   | ...`

With the letters in the brackets identifying client, supplier, user, etc.

The question is, is there a way to normalise our records links table so that we can use it in the most efficient way, while reducing the amount of null values. Is it down to taking a snapshot of the relevant tables and running it down to 2 or 3 NF?

Any help is appreciated.